# How to handle nested views with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, backbone.js

In my app i have a few `tagList`, each one contains a few `tags` grouped by `index_name`.

I'm lost on how should i handle that with Backbone views.

I have a `TagListView` that extends `Backbone.View`, i guess i'll handle all events with this view.

My main question i : should i create a `TagView` with a render function that would be created & rendered for each tag in the `TagListView` render function ?

---

Here is what i do so far in my view : (is this ok for initialization ?!)

```
    <ul id="strategy-tags">
        <!-- initial data -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AppData.strategyTagList = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($strategyTagList); ?>');
            strategyTagListView = new App.TagListView({el : "#strategy-tags", data: AppData.strategyTagList});
        </script>
    </ul>
```

Inside my `core.js` :

```
    App.TagListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // dom event specific to this item.
        events: {
        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.el = options.el;
        },

        render: function() {
            // let's construct the tag list from input data
            _.each(options.data, function(index) {
                // render index? <-- how ?
                _.each(index, function(tag) {
                    // render tag? <-- how ?
                    console.log(tag);
                });
            });
            return this;
        }

    });
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes, the benefit of the individual 'item' view being able to re-render individually is that if you make changes to the model behind such an item, only that item will need to be re-rendered by the browser. Which is best for performance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a question of granularity here, and one I've asked myself on occasion. My advice would be not to over do the views. It is akin to creating objects for everything in java - sometimes a simple string will suffice. If you find a case of increased granularity in the future you can always come back and change it.